# Obtaining Latitude and Longitude with from Spatial objects in R

Tags: r, gdal, rgdal

I want to obtain the latitude and longitude from a shapefile. Until now, I only know how to read the shapefile.

```
library(rgdal)
centroids.mp <- readOGR(".","35DSE250GC_SIR")
```

But how I can extract the latitude and longitude from centroids.mp?

Comment: It's not clear that your question includes "gdal" at all since readShapePoints is in maptools (not rgdal), to really know if the coordinates() solution will work for longitude/latitude we need to see more, like summary(centroids.mp).

Comment: You're right. I already edited the package name. Sorry for this.

Comment: There is no `readShapePoints()` function in **rgdal**, so it's super unclear what you've done and what you are asking for.

Comment: you're right. Sorry again. Aready changed it.

Comment: Put the details about your question/s into the question!  1. do proj4string(centroids.mp) and tell us what that reports. 2. go and read some of the basic documentation for sp/rgdal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a few levels to this question.

You ask for longitude and latitude, but that may not be the coordinate system used by this object. You can get the coordinates like this

```
   coordinates(centroids.mp)
```

Note that the "centroids" will be all of the coordinates if this is a SpatialPointsDataFrame, a list of all the line coordinates if this is a SpatialLinesDataFrame, and just the centroids if this is a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

The coordinates may be longitude and latitude, but the object may not know that. Use

```
   proj4string(centroids.mp)
```

If that is "NA", then the object does not know (A). If it includes "+proj=longlat", the object does know and they are longitude/latitude (B). If it includes "+proj=" and some other name (not "longlat") then the object does know and it's not longitude/latitude (C).

If (A) you'll have to find out, or it might be obvious from the values.

If (B) you are done (though you should check assumptions first, these metadata can be incorrect).

If (C) you can (pretty reliably though you should check assumptions first) transform to longitude latitude (on datum WGS84) like this:

```
 coordinates(spTransform(centroids.mp, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")))
```

Comment: Is it `pro4string` or `proj4string`? (Got an error on the first one)

Comment: proj4string, sorry, fixed now

Answer (score 4):

Use `coordinates()`, like this:

```
library(maptools)
xx <- readShapePoints(system.file("shapes/baltim.shp", package="maptools")[1])
coordinates(xx)
#     coords.x1 coords.x2
# 0       907.0     534.0
# 1       922.0     574.0
# 2       920.0     581.0
# 3       923.0     578.0
# 4       918.0     574.0
#       [.......]
```

Comment: I get an error when I try to open a shape file with maptools. This is the error: "Error in getinfo.shape(filen) : Error opening SHP file". With Rgdal I can read the file. Do you know what's happening?

Comment: Nope. I typically only use `readOGR()` from **rgdal** to read in vector layers. If **rgdal** works, why not just use it and forget about **maptools**?

Comment: Note that it may well not be in longitude/latitude, so use of coordinates() should include a safety check on the proj4string(xx) - and if using rgdal, this could fairly safely include a transformation as well (though making that completely general is probably not safe)

Comment: You're right. I specifid in a wrong way the packages that I am using. I used rgdal not maptools. How can I use proj4string(xx) to get latitudes and longitudes?

Answer (score 1):

`st_coordinates` solve the problem, however it removes removes covariates linked to the coordinates from the sf object. here I share an alternative in case you need them:

```r
# useful enough
sites_sf %>%
  st_coordinates()
#>           X        Y
#> 1 -80.14401 26.47901
#> 2 -80.10900 26.83000

# alternative to keep covariates within a tibble/sf
sites_sf %>%
  st_coordinates_tidy()
#> Joining, by = "rowname"
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 3 fields
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -80.14401 ymin: 26.479 xmax: -80.109 ymax: 26.83
#> epsg (SRID):    4326
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   gpx_point     X     Y             geometry
#>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>          <POINT [°]>
#> 1 a         -80.1  26.5 (-80.14401 26.47901)
#> 2 b         -80.1  26.8      (-80.109 26.83)
```

- complete reprex: https://avallecam.github.io/avallecam/reference/st_coordinates_tidy.html
- source code: https://github.com/avallecam/avallecam/blob/master/R/spatially_useful.R