# Getting longitude and latitude from RDS gadm file

Tags: ggplot2, leaflet, maps

I would like to ask,

is there a way how to get longtitude and latitude variables (in data.frame) from RDS geographic files downloaded for example form: https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html.

I know we can easily plot from this dataset simply using:

```
df2 <- readRDS("C:/Users/petr7/Downloads/gadm36_DEU_1_sp.rds")
library(leaflet)
library(ggplot2)

# Using leaflet
leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron")%>%addPolygons(data=df, weight = 0.5, fill = F)

# Using ggplot
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = df2, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), color = "black", fill = F)
```

how ever even doing `df2$` no long and latitude options are there

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```r
# packages
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3

my_url <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsf/gadm36_ITA_0_sf.rds"
data <- readRDS(url(my_url))

italy_coordinate <- st_coordinates(data)
head(italy_coordinate)
#>             X        Y L1 L2 L3
#> [1,] 12.61486 35.49292  1  1  1
#> [2,] 12.61430 35.49292  1  1  1
#> [3,] 12.61430 35.49347  1  1  1
#> [4,] 12.61375 35.49347  1  1  1
#> [5,] 12.61375 35.49403  1  1  1
#> [6,] 12.61347 35.49409  1  1  1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Now you just to change the url according to your problem. Read the help page of `st_coordinates` function (i.e. `?sf::st_coordinates`) for an explanation of the meaning of L1, L2 and L3 columns.

Comment: Problem solved - for everyone interted see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462290/obtaining-latitude-and-longitude-with-from-spatial-objects-in-r